# Angular Warning Before Leaving a Page Bug

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have defined a host listener to give a warning message when the user tries to leave or reload the page. The thing is, the warning only appears when developer tools are open on the right. If it's not open, it doesn't work. What should I do to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div (window:beforeunload)="onWindowClose($event)"></div>
```

TS:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
onWindowClose(event: any): void {

  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;


   }
```

Comment: This is not an Angular error, but a pure JS error. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#examples for examples on how to use `beforeunload`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using typescript @Akxe

Comment: This does not read as if any warning should be popped, just as if you're preventing the window from being closed in any way. In other words; it looks like the problem described is outside of the provided snippet.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript. EVERYTHING that is part of javascript is part of typescript too. You did not ask the browser to show the prompt. Look at the example in the provided link